# array of unknown size

Tags: python, arrays, shapes

I am pulling data from a .CSV into an array, as follows:

```
my_data = genfromtxt('nice.csv', delimiter='')
a = np.array(my_data)
```

I then attempt to establish the size and shape of the array, thus:

```
size_array=np.size(a)
shape_array=np.shape(a)
```

Now, I want to generate an array of identical shape and size, and then carry out some multiplications. The trouble I am having is generating the correctly sized array. I have tried this:

```
D = np.empty([shape_array,])
```

I receive the error:

> "tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an index".

After investigation my array has a shape of `(248L,)`. Please...how do I get this array in a sensible format?

Thanks.

Comment: Just use `shape_array` directly, without enclosing brackets: `D = np.empty(shape_array)` or even `D = np.empty_like(my_data)`

Comment: Thanks Paul! Much appreciated!

Comment: Note `shape_array` is not an array, it is a tuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `shape_array=np.shape(a)` creates a shape `tuple`, which is the expected input to `np.empty`.

The expression `[shape_array,]` is that `tuple`, wrapped in a `list`, which seems superfluous. Use `shape_array` directly:

```
d = np.empty(shape_array)
```

On a related note, you can use the function [`np.empty_like`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.empty_like.html) to get an array of the same shape and type as the original more effectively:

```
d = np.empty_like(a)
```

If you want to use just the shape and size, there is really no need to store them in separate variables after calling `np.size` and `np.shape`. It is more idiomatic to use the corresponding properties of `np.ndarray` directly:

```
d = np.empty(a.shape)
```